# Need salt, hash login validation advice

Tags: php, database, hash, passwords, salt

My register page looks like this:

```
<?php

    include 'connect.php'; 

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $usercheck = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =    '".$username."'");
    $emailcheck = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'");

    $cost = 10;
    $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
    $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password, $salt);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($usercheck) > 0) 
    {
        echo "username already exist";
    }
    elseif (mysqli_num_rows($emailcheck) > 0) 
    {
        echo"email already exist";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO `database`.`users` (`username`, `password`,  `email`) VALUES ('$username', '$hash', '$email')";
        echo "account created";
        if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        {
            die('error ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The register code work fine, I only have no idea how to login from that.
I have this now
My login code is:

```
<?php

    include 'connect.php';

    $username       = $_POST['username']; 
    $password       = $_POST['password']; 

    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');

    $sth->bindParam(':username', $username);

    $sth->execute();

    $user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // Hashing the password with its hash as the salt returns the same hash
    if ( crypt($password, $user->users) == $user->users ) {

        echo "login?";
    }
        else 
    {
        echo "error?";
    }

?>
```

But it seems this is only for an validation, as result I get an blank page with nothing. Login form is in another script.
I need some advice because when I search the internet it gives something like this back also with `crypt()` login.
Sorry for the no comment in the code.
Thank you in advanced.

EDIT: 
changed the login code to this, but i don't know how to check the hash password:

```
<?php
            include 'connect.php';
    // Define $username and $password
    $username=$_post['username'];
    $password=$_post['password'];


    //Check username and password from database
    $sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'LIMIT 1";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);


    //If username and password exist in our database then create a session.
    //Otherwise echo error.

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
    header("location: register.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    }else
    {
    echo"testwrong";
    }

            ?>
```

Ricardo

Comment: I see mysqli_ code in one then PDO in the other. You're not connecting with mysqli_ for that PDO, are you? If so, you can't mix those up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'm using mysqli to connect with the database $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $adminpassword, $db); so i should change my login to mysqli commands?

Comment: you can't use mysqli to connect with and then using that variable for it in order to query with. You must use the same MySQL API from connection to querying.

Comment: I left out *and using PDO to query with*.

Comment: ok i understand, so i need to change my login script because all other code is in mysqli, i just need to know how i verified my password to login with the register script.

Comment: You compared with the wrong database field `$user->users` instead of `$user->password`. Easier and better would be to use `if (password_verify($password, $user->password))` and `$hash = password_hash($password)` for registering.